# Access three dimensional array via pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

How do I access a three-dimensional array via pointers? At the moment I have this code, trying to get the same results. I need the access via pointers to use the values in the array in OpenCL.

```
for (l = 0; l < NumberOfLayers - 1; l++) {
  for (i = 0; i < NeuronsPerLayer[l]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NeuronsPerLayer[l + 1] - bias[l + 1]; j++) {
      cout<<Synweights[l][i][j]<<endl;  
      cout<<*(*Synweights[0]+l*NumberOfLayers + i * NeuronsPerLayer[l] + j)<<endl;
    }
  }
}
```

`Synweights` is declared as:

```
double ***Synweights
Synweights = (double ** *)malloc((NumberOfLayers - 1) * sizeof(double **));
for (l = 0; l < NumberOfLayers - 1; l++) {
    Synweights[l] = (double **)malloc(NeuronsPerLayer[l] * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < NeuronsPerLayer[l]; i++) {
        Synweights[l][i] = (double *)malloc((NeuronsPerLayer[l + 1] - bias[l + 1]) * sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `Synweights` declared?

Comment: a little piece of advice: avoid using a single `l` as variable name, it's hard to differ from number `1` when syntax-highlight is not on.

Comment: Include the declaration of variables

Comment: If you want to get pointers to the values in the array, just use `&Synweights[l][i][j]`... `&` takes the address of that element.  But, what's the OpenCL interface you want to call?  If you want to pass in elements that aren't all in the same `Synweights[l][i]` contiguous memory region, you may need to allocate differently (e.g. one contiguous allocation, which would have been cleaner/faster/easier anyway).

Comment: @TonyD How do I allocate the Synweights in one contigous Block? I know how to do this with 2 Dimensional Arrays, but not with 3 Dimensions.

Comment: @Bediko Just see my answer below

Comment: @YuHao ...or avoid using single letters as variable names, since it is turns the code unreadable? (With the rare exception of `i`, which every C programmer accepts as the short form of "loop iterator") For this case, something more descriptive than `l, i, j` had actually told us what item in the real world that the various dimensions correspond to.

Comment: @Lundin I got your point but that's not really what I mean, I recommend not using `l` simply because when not in a word, it looks similar with number `1`. Using `i`,`j`,`k` is better.

Comment: @Bediko: Johannes' implementation looks good (`float* p = new float[sizeL*sizeI*sizeJ];`)... you can trivially create a wrapper class to multiple out the indices, as in `double& operator(int l, int i, int j) { return p[(l*sizeI+i)*sizeJ+j]; }` - makes the client code easier to read: `Synweights(l, i, j) += 3;` or whatever....

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the structure of your arrays.

`Synweights` is an array of arrays of arrays which means there are many memory blocks at different locations. If you have a pointer to such a structure you can do the very same with a pointer:

```
float p*** = new float**[sizeL];
for(int l=0; l<sizeL; ++l)
{
    p[l] = new float*[sizeI];
    for(int i=0; i<sizeI; ++i)
        p[l][i] = new float[sizeJ];
}

...
    p[l][i][j] = 0; // Access
```

In case you have just on block of memory which is interpreted as 3D array you need to do some arithmetic. This should be the case you need for CpenCL anyway.

```
float* p = new float[sizeL*sizeI*sizeJ];

...
    p[(l*sizeI+i)*sizeJ+j] = 0; // Access
    p + ((l*sizeI+i)*sizeJ+j);  // Direct address/pointer calculation
```

This variant is faster due to cache performance and less address computations. You can store the computed index if you intend to access more than once.

Answer (score 0):

A three dimensional array may be accessed in the following way;

```
T* myArray = new T[3][4][5];
T* aParticularT = myArray[1][2][2];
T* anArrayOfTs = myArray[1][2];
T* aTwoDimensionalArrayOfTs = myArray[1];
T* aThreeDimensionalArrayOfTs = myArray;
aTypeName aMemberOfT = aParticularT->memberName;
```